# DD4T 2.2 MultimediaField empty when using Model Service

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dd4t-2, model-service

At this moment I have a DD4T 2.2 .NET webapplication which uses the DXA Model Service (SDL Web 8.5). All my fields are working, except for the Multimedia fields.

The image property in the ViewModel object is null:

[image]

My model looks like this:

[image]

But the item is also not available in the Component object:

[image]

**Model Service calls:**

The following calls are done from the webapplication (captured by Fiddler):

[image]

The response of the PageModel call can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/SZku2f6e) (most of the image properties are null). 
The response of the EntityModel can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/fKRYndBT) (image properties are filled).

Rick found out that the Entity Model response is in DXA R2 format (which is a bug?).

The Page Model JSON on the CM-side (using Preview functionality) looks as follows:

```
{
   "Id":"128733",
   "Title":"Home",
   "PageTemplate":{
      "Id":"128931",
      "Title":"Standaard",
      "FileExtension":"html",
      "RevisionDate":"2019-03-19T14:05:57.12"
   },
   "StructureGroupId":"16859",
   "UrlPath":"/index",
   "Meta":{
      "twitter:card":"summary",
      "og:title":"Home",
      "og:type":"article",
      "og:locale":"en-US",
      "og:image":"tcm:135-128756",
      "description":"Home"
   },
   "Regions":[
      {
         "Name":"Main",
         "Entities":[
            {
               "Id":"128938-128930"
            }
         ],
         "MvcData":{
            "ViewName":"Main"
         }
      }
   ],
   "MvcData":{

   },
   "XpmMetadata":{
      "PageID":"tcm:135-128733-64",
      "PageModified":"2019-03-20T18:33:20.063",
      "PageTemplateID":"tcm:135-128931-128",
      "PageTemplateModified":"2019-03-19T14:05:57.12"
   }
}
```

For testing I added the component as Embedded CT on the page, the JSON on CM-side for that page looks like this (multimedia values are filled):

```
{
  "Id": "148023",
  "Title": "Home",
  "PageTemplate": {
    "Id": "148001",
    "Title": "Standaard",
    "FileExtension": "html",
    "RevisionDate": "2019-03-27T07:10:51.883"
  },
  "StructureGroupId": "21456",
  "UrlPath": "/index",
  "Meta": {
    "twitter:card": "summary",
    "og:title": "Home",
    "og:type": "article",
    "og:locale": "en-US",
    "og:image": "tcm:155-147994",
    "description": "Home"
  },
  "Regions": [
    {
      "Name": "Main",
      "Entities": [
        {
          "Id": "147995",
          "ComponentTemplate": {
            "Id": "147998",
            "Title": "Nieuws",
            "RevisionDate": "2019-03-27T09:30:16.433",
            "OutputFormat": "HTML Fragment",
            "Metadata": {
              "controller": "News",
              "action": "ComponentModel",
              "view": "Index"
            }
          },
          "Folder": {
            "Id": "21494",
            "Title": "Nieuws"
          },
          "Content": {
            "title": "Titel",
            "image": {
              "$type": "EntityModelData",
              "Id": "147994",
              "ComponentTemplate": {
                "Id": "147957",
                "RevisionDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
              },
              "Folder": {
                "Id": "21494",
                "Title": "Nieuws"
              },
              "BinaryContent": {
                "Url": "/Preview/Images/logo_tcm155-147994.png",
                "FileName": "logo.png",
                "FileSize": 28332,
                "MimeType": "image/png"
              },
              "SchemaId": "147781"
            },
            "introduction": "Introduction text",
            "paragraphs": {
              "$type": "ContentModelData",
              "title": "Paragraaf 1",
              "body": {
                "$type": "ContentModelData",
                "body": {
                  "$type": "RichTextData",
                  "Fragments": [
                    "\n                <p>Bodytext</p>\n              "
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "MvcData": {
            "ControllerName": "News",
            "ActionName": "ComponentModel",
            "ViewName": "Index"
          },
          "XpmMetadata": {
            "ComponentID": "tcm:155-147995",
            "ComponentModified": "2019-03-27T06:54:07.757",
            "ComponentTemplateID": "tcm:155-147998-32",
            "ComponentTemplateModified": "2019-03-27T09:30:16.433",
            "IsRepositoryPublished": false
          },
          "SchemaId": "147976"
        }
      ],
      "MvcData": {
        "ViewName": "Main"
      }
    }
  ],
  "MvcData": {},
  "XpmMetadata": {
    "PageID": "tcm:155-148023-64",
    "PageModified": "2019-03-27T08:25:19.72",
    "PageTemplateID": "tcm:155-148001-128",
    "PageTemplateModified": "2019-03-27T07:10:51.883"
  }
}
```

The DXA Model Service returns for modelType=DD4T for this page [this result](https://pastebin.com/CV0RjCLh) (multimedia value is null).

Comment: The JSON coming from Model Service which you show is DXA R2 JSON.  However, a DD4T Web Application will retrieve DD4T JSON.  You should have a look at how that DD4T JSON looks like.

Comment: Can you try with  [LinkedComponentField(IsMetadata = true, FieldName = "image")]?

Comment: @RickPannekoek, the Model Converter of the DXA Model service has converted the JSON because of the parameter 'modelType=DD4T' (you can see it in screenshot). @ Velmurugan, your suggestion gives the same result.

Comment: @Velmurugan, is there a reason you suggest to use 'IsMetadata = true'?

Comment: In case if you want to access the image meta field values if any? otherwise, make it false, some cases you may have AlText field to get the meta title field to get the values then you can also create a customImage class to get that meta field values

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan, see my update. The value is not available in the DD4T component itself. Could it be that this is an issue related to DD4T in combination with the DXA Model Service?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that the JSON Response is *not* DD4T JSON, but DXA R2 JSON.

Comment: @RickPannekoek, I updated my question with the full JSON responses. The multimedia field is the only field that is not working, other fields are mapped correctly in my DD4T application.

Comment: Interesting. The Page Model JSON is DD4T JSON, the Entity Model JSON is not.

Comment: @RickPannekoek, do you know which call is used by DD4T, because in the Page Model JSON also the CP's are filled.

Comment: Indeed, a Page Model contains Entity Models (representing CPs on the Page). The Model Service’s EntityModel endpoint is used to retrieve DCPs separately (not in context of a Page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is now reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/issues/10). I found out that there are multiple issues when working with the DXA Model Service together with DD4T. There is an [issue related to keywords](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19935/content-service-breaks-when-content-tagged-with-keyword-is-being-requested-via-d) and there seems also to be an issue with the `DD4T.Providers.DxaModelService` package, when retrieving Component Presentations with the methods: `ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentation` (throws an error) and `ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentations` (most of the fields are null).

Because of all the articles about the possibility to use the Model Service together with DD4T and the fact that it is supported by SDL I thought it would be a good approach. Now it seems to me that I am the first one ever using this approach on a 'real' project and there is still some work to do.

Since we are at the beginning of our project and facing these kind of issues we decided to stop using this approach en go for the approach DD4T together with the Content Service by using the `DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8.5.CIL` package instead of using `DD4T.Providers.DxaModelService`.

The reason I choose for the DD4T + DXA Model Service approach is mostly because of [this article](http://dd4t.org/dxa2.html). I was charmed by the promised performance gain. I also share the vision that I prefer a Framework (DD4T) over an customizable webapplication (which DXA is at this moment). When DXA Core is there (the framework) I will surely migrate the application.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for all the hurdles you hit. I think you’re right that you are one of the first to try this configuration in the field.

Comment: BTW: in general, the DD4T support in DXA Model Service is intended for migration of existing DD4T Web Apps, but this sounds like you were considering it for a new implementation?  Could you elaborate on the requirements and the reasoning behind choosing a DD4T Web App vs. a DXA Web App or “the Content Service approach” ?

Comment: @RickPannekoek, good questions, I updated my question ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that helps to define the future of DXA.  Note that DXA is a Framework (+ *example* Web App) too.  Would be nice to understand what people consider too limiting at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your scenario, your View Model represents a Component Presentation which is part of a Page, we can focus on the Page Model JSON (which is correctly DD4T JSON).

There is a problem with this Page Model JSON: you can see that the “image” field is a MultiMedia link field and the JSON includes the expanded linked MM Component.  However the `Multimedia` property of the expanded MM Component is `null`.

This is potentially a defect in the R2->DD4T conversion in the DXA Model Service.

Can you provide the DXA R2 Page Model JSON as generated by the CM System (that is: do a CM Preview on the Page)?

Comment: I added the requested JSON. The Page Template has the 'Render Page Content' TBB assigned.

Comment: Ok, so apparently the Page contains a DCP which isn’t expanded on CM-side, but in the Model Service. Might be part of the issue. Could you try with an embedded CP?

Comment: when I add an MultiMedia component via an embedded schema, the MultiMedia property is also null. When I add a it via an Component Link, the Model Service throws a 500 error.

Comment: As addition on my last comment, when I do the same call with parameter modelType=R2 then the call doesn't fail. So there seems to be an issue in the Model Service indeed.

Comment: For clarity: I meant using an embedded CP (so not a dynamic CT) and then check how the DXA Page Model generated by CM looks (CM Preview). Next question would be how the Page Model generated by MS looks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reponse, we had an issue with our development environment. It is getting very interesting, when I configure the CT to be 'Published Embedded on a Page' the DXA Model service responds with a 404. The same call with parameter modelType=R2 gives a 200 result (looks good)

Comment: Hmmm... How does the DXA R2 Page Model generated by CM look (CM Preview) when the CP is embedded?

Comment: Wait a moment, I see that the 404 is related to another issue (the dev server issue I mentioned in my last comment). Will come back to you later

Comment: Added the  requested JSON results to my question.

Comment: Ok that DXA R2 JSON looks fine (properly expanded "image" MM Component link field).  Now how does the DD4T JSON provided by the Model Service look for that Page?

Comment: That is in the link I added below the CM-side JSON (https://pastebin.com/CV0RjCLh).

Comment: Oh sorry, didn’t notice that one earlier.  So, I think we can conclude now that it is an issue in the Model Service’s R2->DD4T conversion logic. Please create an Issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/issues

Comment: BTW, the code which does the R2->DD4T conversion is here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/blob/master/java/dxa-model-service/dxa-model-service-controller/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modelservice/service/processing/conversion/ToDd4tConverterImpl.java