# Content Service breaks when content tagged with keyword is being requested via DXA Model Service DD4T

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dd4t-2, model-service

At this moment I have a DD4T 2.2 .NET web application which uses the DXA Model Service (SDL Web 8.5). I am able to retrieve 'normal' fields correctly. I have [another question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19905/dd4t-2-2-multimediafield-empty-when-using-model-service) open about MultiMedia fields, but now I am facing also 
an issue with keywords.

I added a keyword field (as embedded schema) to my component and when I request the page I get a 500 error from the Model Service

```
{
    "timestamp": [
        "String",
        "2019-03-27T13:09:02.718+0000"
    ],
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException",
    "message": "Retry limit exceeded.",
    "path": "/PageModel/tcm/155/index"
}
```

After checking the Windows Services, I found out that my Content Service stops every time I request that page (which explains the result of the DXA Model Service).

The logging of the Content Service can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/cuf89zsV).

The logging of the DXA Model Service can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/PLNRVBhf).

The request does work if I request it as R2 data. But since I am using DD4T it is requested as DD4T, so maybe an error in the Model Service converter?

Comment: Increase the logging level of the Model service in the logback.xml file, restart the Model service and check in the logs for anything unusual and double check is there any item missed to published, configure to increase model service timeout, https://www.exlrt.com/blog/dxa-2-0-model-service-timeout-and-retry

Comment: @Velmurugan, I already added the logs and they are also already on DEBUG level. The Model Service gives a retry error because the Content Service breaks and is not available after that. So we have to investigate why the Content Service breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try publishing the keyword objects themselves to the Broker that are used in the Page.  The new Publishing Model does not include the keyword information at publish time, and instead tries to request it at Delivery time from the Broker, and for this, you will need the keyword published.  I recall seeing this in the SDL Live Docs but cannot find it at this moment.

Comment: For clarity: publishing of Keywords/Taxonomies is only needed for Taxonomies which are "publishable" in the first place;  if a Taxonomy is not publishable, its Keywords will be expanded on CM-side.  This is less error-prone, but the disadvantage is that the Keyword data gets embedded in potentially many Pages/DCPs,  which may have to be republished when the Keyword data changes.

Comment: The category is published. And when I request the DXA Model Service with parameter modelType=R2, then I get a good result. When it is request as modelType=DD4T it breaks.